# Load HTML File in LibreOffice using Python

Tags: python, add-in, libreoffice, uno

I've been asked to make an extension to LibreOffice, where I'd have to show a WebPage to the user. Imagine that what my extension's purpose is to open [Google](https://www.google.pt) . Is there a way I can program this with Python? I thinked of using loadComponentFromUrl, but would that work?

Comment: loadComponentFromURL() can load HTML. Try it, and you will see.
And yes, it can be done in Python, too.  
But I think you won't like it: just CTRL+O within LO and put your URL, hit Enter and wait. This will be your output, layouted by LO.   
You see my point?

Comment: Did you check out the python code that I suggested or have you now moved on to a Java solution?

Comment: @RolfofSaxony I've moved to a Java Solution (:

Answer (score 1):

See the code that I posted here:
[Pyuno indexing issue that I would like an explanation for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32411714/pyuno-indexing-issue-that-i-would-like-an-explanation-for)

It is a working python macro that sends text selected in a libreoffice writer document to either duckduckgo or google. It should be easily adaptable for your needs.

Let me know if you need help with it.